# Получение 10 последних видео с канала на Youtube по URL

Tags: python, youtube-api

Как получить id последних 10 видео с любого канала YouTube, имея только ссылку на канал, учитывая, что ссылки есть разных видов?
Если по ссылке на канал это сделать нельзя, то как это сделать по id канала?

Comment: А провести хоть какое-то расследование через сам браузер не пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вам нужно посмотреть [API YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3?hl=ru)** . Там вы найдете документацию о том, как получить доступ к API.

Вы можете сделать запросы самостоятельно. Вот пример URL-адреса, который извлекает последние видео с канала:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API ключ}&channelId={id канала}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

Где **maxResults=10** максимальное количество видео в ответе, **order** - сортировка (*в данном случае date - по дате*), **key** - ваш API ключ, **channelId** - id канала
После этого вы получите сообщение JSON с идентификаторами видео и подробностями, и вы сможете создать URL-адрес видео следующим образом:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id_here}
```

Так же есть [клиентская библиотека для Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)